# java httpsession is valid?

Tags: java, servlets, httpsession

I'm using the java servlet API in tomcat.

I save in a hash table the username and the httpsession with the attribute username and I would like to know if there is a way to check if the httpsession is valid.

I've tried:

```
try {
    String user = httpSession.getAttribute("username")
    return "is valid";
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    return "is not valid";
}
```

What can I do if I don't want that a "logged" user connect from more than one place? If I control only if I create a new session, I can't know if he was connected already with another session.

Answer (score 10):

No need to store the httpSession in your own hash.

Look at the API for the [HttpServletRequest](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html). If you look at method [getSession(Boolean x)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29) (pass false so it doesn't create a new session) will determine if the session is valid.

Here is an example

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
    
    if (session == null) {
       //valid session doesn't exist
       //do something like send the user to a login screen
    }

    if (session.getAttribute("username") == null) {
       //no username in session
       //user probably hasn't logged in properly
    }

    //now let's pretend to log the user out for good measure
    session.invalidate();
}
```

On a side note, If I read your question properly and you are storing the information in your own map, you need to be careful that you don't create a memory leak and are clearing the entries out of the hash table yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Sean.  I will add that a good practice for this type of checking is to use a Filter

See here [Servlet Filter](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/Filter.html)

Just take the code Sean have written and put it in a Filter instead.  Define you filter in the web.xml and every time a request come in, the filter will execute.

This way you can validate if the user is auth. without cluttering your servlet code.

Comment: Yeah filter will work. I wanted to show the basics in my example.
with one servlet, it is ok to do this check in the servlet but becomes very cluttered when you start managing multiple servlets. Moving to a filter is better in that case

Comment: You are right, and your response was very good.. just wanted to add my 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking if a saved session is valid, you should be looking at the `HttpServletRequest` on your servlet, and checking `isRequestedSessionIdValid()` on that. When working in servlets you can always get `Session` from the `Request`, rather than saving it to a hash table.

Comment: That's actually not that helpful, because you still have to deal with (or accept) the possibility of an Illegal StatException there. Because in the microsecond between the check and the session get, the session could be invalidated.

Comment: My (perhaps incorrect) assumption would be that the moment tomcat sees the session id, before passing the request for the servlet, it would check to see if it was timed out yet, and if not reset the time to keep the session alive for whatever the default session length is. No?

Comment: But you could have a logout request at the same time. Multithreads, multi servlets, remember?