# I can't save session attributes with HttpSession

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-client, httpsession

I'm doing a loggin test app that recive username and password in JSON format and compare the value with the DB. But for some reason the session it's not saved.
This is the method that I use for validate the user info and save the session:

```
@POST
@Path("/login")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response userLogin(Usuario us , @Context HttpServletRequest rq){
    HttpSession session ;
    //Search for the user with the username provided
    Usuario user = usuarioService.getUsuario(us);
    //Verify that user != to null

    if(user != null){
        //verify that password be the same that provided by the client
        if(user.getPassword().equals(us.getPassword())){
            //Set new Attribute in the session with the user info
            session = rq.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("username" , user.getUsername());
            return Response.ok().entity("User:" +user.getUsername() +  "has started session with success " + "Session ID : " +session.getId()).build();
        }
        else{
            return Response.ok().entity("Wrong password, please verify and try again" ).build();
        }
    }else{
        return Response.ok().entity("User : "+ us.getUsername()+ " name not found").build();
    }
}
```

The problems come when  I try to call the session attribute 'username' where the user name has been saved.
When I try to use a method that retrive the current session id, I found that it's not the same session id that when the username attribute has been added.
The method that I use to verify the session info next:

```
@GET
@Path("/checkSession")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response userLoginCheck(@Context HttpServletRequest rq){
    //Call the current session information
    HttpSession session = rq.getSession(false);
    String msg;
    //Verify if the session is new and return not session available
    if( session == null){
        msg = " Session not available" + session.getId();
        return Response.ok().entity(msg).build();
    }else if(session.getAttribute("username") == null){
        msg = "Has been not possible call the required session SESSION ID : " + session.getId();
        return Response.ok().entity(msg).build();
    }
    else{ //If session != null  & attribute 'username' exist, then call 'username' attribute from the session
        return Response.ok().entity(session.getAttribute("user")).build();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or idea to solve it.

Comment: How do you test it? Sessions are (in most cases) stored in cookies. You test framework (browser?) must support cookies. Check if JSESESSION cookie is not getting lost.

Comment: I'm testint it with a web form from my browser. The coockie JSESESSION exist but don't have the same key value that the method session.getID() return. I'll test with Postman

Comment: That is strange. Both browser and postman should retain cookies. What is you application server? Is it possible session cookies are disabled on the server level? Check the session timeout (in web.xml). It is possible set to very small value.

Comment: Look like the problem can be in the Cors Filter that I've configured due to with Postman save session info without problem. I'm reading this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711004/java-httpsession-is-valid?rq=1) and I will try to save the session info from the Filter